# How to auto-mount external drive without using /etc/fstab

Tags: rhel, automounting, device-mapper

I have mounted an external drive using an entry`/etc/fstab` , `UUID=ba6274de-e241-43ef-9dd0-5147c29e883a /mnt/500GB_Seagate_Drive xfs defaults,x-gvfs-show 0 0`

I have other drives with do not have an entry in `/etc/fstab` . How can i mount this drive in the same way using device mapper without making an entry in `/etc/fstab` . I am not sure how they are getting automounted on boot.

[image]

Using `/etc/fstab` does not show the mounted drive on the left like the other auto-mounted drives show in the left like this:

[image]

output of mount for auto-mounted drives:

```
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ mount | grep WD5TB
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/munish259272/WD5TB type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota,uhelper=udisks2)
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ 
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ mount | grep 'My Passport'
/dev/sdc1 on /run/media/munish259272/My Passport type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uhelper=udisks2` in the output of `mount` indicates that these mounts are done by `udisksd`. It is a typical component for handling the privileged parts of user mount operations with several desktop environments.

As the mounts are tied to your GUI login session, they don't happen at boot, but when you login (using the GUI). Your desktop environment should have a way to control the mounts.

See also `udisksctl status` and `udisksctl dump` to get more information on things `udisksd` thinks are mountable, but essentially the same information should be available somewhere in the settings tool of your desktop environment too.